# MVC3 Validation: Change element class when invalid

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc-3, css-selectors

I'm using server validation and want to change the element class when invalid.
So for example I have a textbox with a validationmessage:

```
@Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.FirstName, new {@class = "error"})
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.FirstName, new {@class = "aftererror"})
```

When the textbox data is invalid I want the textbox to get a red border.
I tried to change it using css selectors:

```
 .error + .aftererror
    {   
        border:solid 1px red;
        }
```

so when the validationmessage is showing, the textbox would get the "aftererror" class.
Unfortunately the validation element is also showing even if the data is valid, only there is no text.

So how would I change the css class of the texbox on error, or have the validation element disappear when there's no error.

Answer (score 12):

This is already built into ASP.NET MVC.

Take a read through [Scott Gu's blog post on MVC Validation](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/01/15/asp-net-mvc-2-model-validation.aspx).

Basically the framework is setup to automagically add a `input-validation-error` css class to invalid fields.

Here's the CSS I use to add the red border and pinkish background (it's [DotLess](http://www.dotlesscss.org/) so not exactly what the CSS will look like)

```
.field-validation-error
{
    color: @valid-dark;
}

.field-validation-valid
{
    display: none;
}

input.input-validation-error,
textarea.input-validation-error,
select.input-validation-error
{
    border: 1px solid @valid-dark ;
    background-color: @valid-light;
    font-size:100%;
}

.validation-summary-errors
{
    font-weight: bold;
    color: @valid-dark;
    ul{
        display: none;
    }
}

.validation-summary-valid
{
    display: none;
}
```

<sub>just make sure you also have the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` added to your page. It helps with all the validation goodness</sub>

Comment: The problem is that the .field-validation-.. classes are not being added to my textbox. I figured out this is because I'm validating a property, and the ModelError doesn't map to the textbox.

Comment: Your property is called FirstName. So you need to create a buddy class to that property and add the validation logic. Then it will be applied all the way down the line.

Comment: Is there a way to add another class except the default `.field-validation-error` etc.?

Answer (score 4):

In MVC4 it is:

```
.input-validation-error
{
     border: 1px solid red !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The .field-validation classes will apply to properties, but are likely being overridden, probably by

```
input[type="text"]
```

Set the styles of .input-validation-error (NOT .field-validation-error) to !important or get rid of input[type="text"] from the stylesheet.